# moving value from one multiselect picklist to other

Tags: visualforce

I am trying move values from one multiselect picklist to other. Assume that there are 2 multiselect picklist A and B. Now I have to move some values from picklist A to B by clicking on the Add button and need to remove the values from B by using remove button. I am able to move values from A to B, but when it get added it display a duplicate of the moved value to. That is if I move 1  value 2 values are getting displayed on B from A. And when I try to remove the value from B the new duplicate value of B get created there. I am using a map to populate with the select option and looping this map to add the values to the select option. Also remove the key from map to remove the moved value from A. But I am facing the problem of duplication of value. Please anyone here can help me out to get the solution on this issue.
VF page :

```
<apex:page controller="filterScreen_ctrl" sidebar="false">

<style type="text/css">
   * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
   #container {height: 100%; width:100%; font-size: 0;}
   #left, #middle, #right {display: inline-block; *display: inline; zoom: 1; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px;}
   #left {width: 20%; padding-left: 2%; }
  #middle {width: 5%; padding-top: 6%;}
  #right {width: 20%; }
 </style>
 <apex:form >  

  <apex:actionFunction name="rightArrow" action="{!addFields}" reRender="selectionBlock"/>

   <apex:pageBlock >
       <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
           <apex:outputText value="Select Object : "></apex:outputText>
              <apex:selectList value="{!objectName}" size="1">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!orgObjects}"/>
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!RelatedFields}"/>
              </apex:selectList>
       </apex:pageBlockSection> 


       <!--<apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!if(objectName != null, true, false)}">-->
       <apex:panelBar rendered="{!if(objectName != null, true, false)}" id="mainPanal" >
       <apex:panelBarItem label="Related Fields" >
        <div id="container">           

            <div id="left">
                <br/><br/><br/><br/> 
                <apex:outputText value="Available Field : "></apex:outputText><br/>
                <apex:selectList value="{!FiledName}" size="6" multiselect="true" id="FiledID">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!objFields}"/>
                    <!--<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!addFields}"/>-->
                </apex:selectList>
            </div>  

            <div id="middle">
                <apex:outputText value="ADD"></apex:outputText><br/>
                <apex:commandButton  action="{!addFields}" value=">>" reRender="selFiledID, FiledID"/>
                <br/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!removeFields}" value="<<" reRender="FiledID, selFiledID"/><br/>
                <apex:outputText value="REMOVE"></apex:outputText>
            </div>  

            <div id="right">
                <br/><br/><br/><br/>
                <apex:outputText value="Selected Fields"></apex:outputText><br/>

                <apex:selectList value="{!selFiledName}" size="6" id="selFiledID" multiselect="true" >
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!filterFields}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </div> 


        </div>  
       </apex:panelBarItem>
       </apex:panelBar>     
       <!--</apex:pageBlockSection>-->


   </apex:pageBlock>
```

controller :

```
global class filterScreen_ctrl {

public Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
public String objectName {get; set;}
//public String[] FiledName {get; set;}
public String FiledName {get; set;}
public List<String> holdSelectedFiledName {get; set;}
public String selFiledName {get; set;}
public List<Filter_Field_Set__c> FilterField_Lst {get; set;}
public List<String> selectedFieldname_lst {get; set;}

public Map<String, String> selectedFieldname_map {get; set;}
public String selectedFieldname ;
public String SelectedLayout {get; set;}

public List<SelectOption> option_Sfield = new List<SelectOption>();
public List<SelectOption> option_Obfield = new List<SelectOption>();

public map<string, string> selFiledName_map = new map<string, string>();
public map<string, string> FiledName_map = new map<string, string>();

public set<string> FiledName_set = new set<string>();
public set<string> selFiledName_set = new set<string>();

public filterScreen_ctrl (){

    FilterField_Lst = new List<Filter_Field_Set__c>();
    selectedFieldname_lst = new List<String>();
    selectedFieldname_map = new Map<String, String>();
    holdSelectedFiledName = new List<String>();

    //selFiledName = new String[]();
    //FiledName = new String[]{};
    //objectName = 'Account';   
}

public List<selectoption> getorgObjects(){

    List<SelectOption> option_obj = new List<SelectOption>();
    option_obj.add(new SelectOption('--Select--' , '--Select--'));
    for(String objectvalue: schemaMap.keyset()){
        option_obj.add(new SelectOption(objectvalue, schemaMap.get(objectvalue).getDescribe().getLabel()));
    }

    return option_obj;

}

public string RelatedFields(){

    system.debug('Selected Filed Name ' + FiledName);

    FilterField_Lst = [SELECT Name, Object_Fields_Name__c FROM Filter_Field_Set__c WHERE Name = :objectName];

    for(integer i = 0; i <FilterField_Lst.size(); i++){
        selectedFieldname = string.valueof(FilterField_Lst[i].Object_Fields_Name__c);
        selectedFieldname_lst = selectedFieldname.split(',&,');
    }

    for(integer i=0; selectedFieldname_lst.size() > i; i++){
        selectedFieldname_map.put(selectedFieldname_lst[i], selectedFieldname_lst[i]);
    }   

    system.debug('Selected Field Name map ' + selectedFieldname_map);
    system.debug('value of FiledName in RelatedFields ' + FiledName);
    //if(FiledName == null){   
        getfilterFields();
        getobjFields();
    //}
    return null;
}

public List<selectoption> getobjFields(){

    //option_Obfield.clear();

    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    if(FiledName != null && FiledName != ''){
        option_Obfield.clear();
        if(FiledName.contains('[')){
            FiledName = FiledName.replace('[', '');
            FiledName = FiledName.replace(']', '');
        }

        for(String selectedField : FiledName.split(',')){
            FiledName_set.add(selectedField);
        }

        for(String sfield: fieldMap.keyset()){
            if(FiledName_set.contains(sfield)){
                FiledName_map.remove(sfield);
            }
        }
     }         
     else{
        for(String sfield: fieldMap.keyset()){
            FiledName_map.put(sfield, fieldMap.get(sfield).getDescribe().getLabel() );
        }
     }


     /*
     if(selFiledName != null && selFiledName != ''){
        //option_Obfield.clear();
        if(selFiledName.contains('[')){
            selFiledName = selFiledName.replace('[', '');
            selFiledName = selFiledName.replace(']', '');
        }

        for(String selectedField : selFiledName.split(',')){
            FiledName_set.add(selectedField);
        }

        for(String sfield: fieldMap.keyset()){
            if(FiledName_set.contains(sfield)){
                FiledName_map.remove(sfield);
            }
        }
     }       
     */

     for(String FiledNames : FiledName_map.keyset()){
        system.debug('Filed Names inside map loop ' + FiledNames);
        option_Obfield.add(new SelectOption(FiledNames , FiledName_map.get(FiledNames) ));
     }



     system.debug('option Object field ' + option_Obfield);
     return option_Obfield;

}

public List<selectoption> getfilterFields(){

    //List<SelectOption> option_Sfield = new List<SelectOption>();
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    if(selFiledName != null && selFiledName != ''){  
        selFiledName_set.clear();
        system.debug('value of selFiledName before split ' + selFiledName);         
        if(selFiledName.contains('[')){
            selFiledName = selFiledName.replace('[', '');
            selFiledName = selFiledName.replace(']', '');
        }
        system.debug('loop before split  ' + selFiledName);
        for(String selectedField : selFiledName.split(',')){
            selFiledName_set.add(selectedField);
        }
        system.debug('Set filed name ' + selFiledName_set);
        for(String sfield: fieldMap.keyset()){
            system.debug('Field Map value ' + sfield);
            if(selFiledName_set.contains(sfield)){
                system.debug('if value contains in selFiledName_set ' + selFiledName_set);
                system.debug('if value in sfield ' + sfield);
                selFiledName_map.remove(sfield);
            }
            system.debug(' value of map after remove ' + selFiledName_map);
        }

        //for(String selFileds: selFiledName_map.keyset()){
            //selFiledName_map.put(selFileds, fieldMap.get(selFileds.trim()).getDescribe().getLabel());
        //}

    }
    else{
        for(integer i =0; selectedFieldname_lst.size() > i; i++){
            if(!selFiledName_map.containsKey(selectedFieldname_lst[i] )){
                selFiledName_map.put(selectedFieldname_lst[i], fieldMap.get(selectedFieldname_lst[i]).getDescribe().getLabel());
            }
        }
    }



    if(FiledName != null && FiledName != ''){           
        selFiledName_set.clear();
        system.debug('value before split ' + FiledName);
        for(String selectedField : FiledName.split(',')){
            if(FiledName.contains('[')){
                selectedField = selectedField.replace('[', '');
            }
            if(FiledName.contains(']')){
                selectedField = selectedField.replace(']', '');
            }
            system.debug('loop through split  ' + selectedField);
            selFiledName_set.add(selectedField);
        }

        system.debug('Values in set ' + selFiledName_set);
        for(String sfield: selFiledName_set){
            //if(selFiledName_set.contains(sfield)){
                selFiledName_map.put(sfield, sfield);
            //}
        }
    }


    system.debug('Values in map  ' + selFiledName_map);

    if(selFiledName_map != null ){
    for(String selFiledNamemap: selFiledName_map.keyset()){
        system.debug('sel Filed Name in map ' + selFiledNamemap);
        system.debug('Field map to get label ' + fieldMap.get(selFiledNamemap.trim()));
        if(selFiledNamemap != null && selFiledNamemap != ''){                           
                option_Sfield.add(new SelectOption(selFiledNamemap , fieldMap.get(selFiledNamemap.trim()).getDescribe().getLabel() ));
        }
    }
    }
    else{
        selFiledName_map.clear();
    }



    /*
    system.debug('All the fields from the object ' + fieldMap);

    system.debug('value in FiledName' + FiledName);

    if(FiledName != null){
        system.debug('Inside If condition ');
        if(FiledName.contains('[')){
            FiledName = FiledName.replace('[', '');
            FiledName = FiledName.replace(']', '');
        }
        for(String selectedField : FiledName.split(',')){
            system.debug('Selected and added fields ' + selectedField);
            system.debug('Selected in map  ' + fieldMap.get(selectedField.trim()));
            if(!selFiledName_map.containsKey(selectedField)){
                selFiledName_map.put(selectedField, selectedField);
                option_Sfield.add(new SelectOption(selectedField , selectedField ));
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        system.debug('Inside else condition ');
        for(integer i =0; selectedFieldname_lst.size() > i; i++){
            if(!selFiledName_map.containsKey(selectedFieldname_lst[i] )){
                selFiledName_map.put(selectedFieldname_lst[i], fieldMap.get(selectedFieldname_lst[i]).getDescribe().getLabel());
                option_Sfield.add(new SelectOption(selectedFieldname_lst[i] , fieldMap.get(selectedFieldname_lst[i]).getDescribe().getLabel() ));
            }
        }

    }
    */

    return option_Sfield;

}

//Radio Button
public List<selectoption> getLayout(){

    List<selectOption> option_layout = new List<selectOption>();
    option_layout.add(new selectOption('Filter_Field', 'Filter Field'));
    option_layout.add(new selectOption('Update_Field', 'Update Field'));        
    return option_layout;

}




public string addFields(){

    getfilterFields(); 
    getobjFields();

    FiledName = null;


    return null;

}

public PageReference removeFields(){

    FiledName = null;

    //getobjFields();
    getfilterFields(); 

    selFiledName = null;
    return null;    
}
}
```

Please guide me to find the solution for this issue. Please let know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: As I commented yesterday, you may be better off using this [Multiselect Picklist Visualforce Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/06/a-multiselect-picklist-visualforce-component.html) rather than building this from scratch - that component is known to work.

Comment: Gotta agree with @KeithC here.  Don't reinvent the wheel...

Comment: but my client is not ready to install any app to his org. He just need to be done by us only.

Comment: The link I mentioned mentions that you can "grab the source from GitHub" and the license terms listed [here](https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist) allow re-distribution of the source code. So you can just pull the code into our project so it becomes part of your project. Usually customers prefer the lower priced option of you re-using the work of others where appropriate.